# How do I prevent my "production" group from being called when running in my Rails development enviornment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, puma

Im using Rails 4.2.7 on Mac OS X (El Capitan).  I have this at the end of my Gemfile (for my production environment).  I have no other references to puma in my Gmefile …

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'unicorn'
  gem 'puma'
end
```

but when I attempt to start my Rails server on my development machine (my Mac), it is attempting to start up Puma …

```
localhost:networkingproject localuser$ rails s -b 127.0.0.1
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 4.2.7.1 application starting in development on http://127.0.0.1:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[93431] Puma starting in cluster mode...
[93431] * Version 3.6.0 (ruby 2.3.0-p0), codename: Sleepy Sunday Serenity
[93431] * Min threads: 1, max threads: 6
[93431] * Environment: development
[93431] * Process workers: 1
[93431] * Phased restart available
[93431] * Listening on tcp://127.0.0.1:3000
[93431] Use Ctrl-C to stop
localhost:networkingproject localuser$
```

I don’t have a RAILS_ENV set.  The below echoes nothing …

```
localhost:networkingproject localuser$ echo $RAILS_ENV
```

How do I make Rails run without Puma (just normally) in my development (Mac) environment?

**Edit:** Output in response to suggestion given …

```
localhost:networkingproject localuser$ rails s -b 127.0.0.1
Could not find gem 'puma' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, are you sure you don't have puma gem installed (not from your Gemfile)? Try

`gem list`

to check it and

`gem uninstall puma`

if you have it and want to remove it to be sure

Anyway, usually `bundle install --without production` do the trick